# Finding stopping time when only given initial angular velocity and an expression for angular acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-velocity, rotation, rotational-kinematics

Question:

> A wheel starts is spinning at $27\text{ rad/s}$ but is slowing with an angular
>   acceleration that has a magnitude given by $\alpha(t) = (3.0\;\mathrm{rad/s^4})t^2$. It stops in a time of:  $\qquad$  ?

I happened to guess $3.0\text{ s}$ and it turned out to be right.  But I want to understand why.

I tried using a kinematics equation and plugging $a$ in for $\alpha$, but it gave me the wrong answer.  Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to take the integral of the acceleration function, then since at t=0 w=27, my velocity function would be `w = t^3 + 27.` From there, it's just a simple matter of plugging in 0 for the final velocity and solving for t.

Comment: That sounds correct!